# Ember.js: how to add parameters to a View

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I guess this is simple but as an Ember newbie I cannot find a solution...

So let's say I have this very simple view:

```
MyApp.MyTextView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{value}}')
});
```

And I want to use this view in order to display two different properties of the same object. This sounds like I want to add parameters when I 'call' my view.
In a second view I want to be able to do something like the following (supposing my content object is a Person : {firstName: 'toto', lasName: 'titi'}):

```
MyApp.AnotherView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('FirstName: {{view MyApp.MyTextView value="content.firstName"}} - LastName: {{view MyApp.MyTextView value="content.lastName"}}')
});
```

I also tried to use Handlebars helpers as explained [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/), but It does not work (when I use {{highlight firstName}} or {{highlight content.firstName}} what is displayed is firstName or content.firstName, not the property value...)

Do you guys have any idea? I'm stuck here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To pass in parameters to your view, you can specify each one like so:

```
{{view App.MyView firstNameBinding="content.firstName" lastNameBinding="content.lastName"}}
```

Which would allow you to do:

```
template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view.firstName view.lastName}}');
```

However, you can imagine that this will get **very** long as you add more properties. Therefore you can instead simply pass in your `content` object as the `context` (but you don't need to pass it in as context -- although that's for another day):

```
{{view App.MyView contextBinding="content"}}
```

*(Please note that `contextBinding` is special, and changes the context in the view.)*

That way the view will hold the object you pass in, and so in your view you can now do:

```
template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{firstName lastName}}');
```

*(You can do it like this because `content` is now your view's context.)*

I've knocked you up a quick JSFiddle to elucidate (hopefully!): http://jsfiddle.net/YVCrq/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The second solution looks good but the first one suits more my needs because I want to adress one single object property and not a whole object (so that MyTextView is 'generic'). I changed a little bit your JSFiddle in order to test the first solution but nothing is displayed... Is there something wrong with it? => http://jsfiddle.net/YVCrq/1/

Comment: +1 thank you very much, if you want, you can answer my similar question there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564750/ember-js-compare-values-in-dom-if-statement-or-at-least-in-a-view-with-value-fro

Comment: It looks good to me, reef. I've just got it working for you by changing the content, just in case it confuses other people: http://jsfiddle.net/YVCrq/2/

Comment: Giedrius: Did ken answer your question adequately?

Comment: Thank you so much Wildhoney! You saved my day ;)